# R Drop rows according to various criteria

Tags: r

I need some help regarding how to start the implementation a problem in R. I have a data frame with rows which are grouped by the variable 'id'. For each 'id' I want to keep only one row. However, I have a number of criteria which specify which rows to drop.

These are some of my criteria:

1. I want to keep one random row within each group 'id' which has 'text' != NA (there might be several such rows); and I also want to keep all columns of this row, this is also the case for all following criteria.
2. If all rows in a group have 'text' == NA, then I want to keep one random row which has the variable 'check' == T (there might be several such rows)
3. If all rows in a group have 'text' == NA and 'check' == F, then I want to keep the row which has the variable 'newtext' which meets the condition !(grepl("None",df$newtext))

I can also provide a dataset if this makes it more clear. However, my most important issue is that I do not know how to implement this logic of dropping rows according to an ordered number of criteria.
It would be nice, if anyone can tell me how to implement such a code.

Thank you!

This would be an example dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
             text=c("asd",NA,"asd",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
             check = c(T,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,F),
             newtext = 
c("as","as","as","das","das","None","qwe","qwe2","None"),
             othervars = c(1,2,3,45,5,6,6,7,1))
```

As an output, I want to keep the following rows:
row 1 or 3
row 4 or 5
row 7 or 8
The column othervars should be kept as well as I need this information later on.

Hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide the dataset or relevant sections of the dataset. That would save us a lot of time writing any code that you could implement for y our numerous conditions.

Comment: i added a minimal dataset. hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've got something. I'm using `filter()` from `dplyr` to subset with unknown `NA`, because I ran into problems using either `subset()` or common `df[,]` subsetting from base `R`.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
             text=c("asd",NA,"asd",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
             check = c(T,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,F),
             newtext = 
c("as","as","as","das","das","None","qwe","qwe2","None"),
             othervars = c(1,2,3,45,5,6,6,7,1))
```

Initiating new empty dataframe:

```
df2 <- df[0,]
```

Loop to sample one row per `id`:

```
library(dplyr)

for(i in unique(df$id)){
  temp <- filter(df, id == i)
  if(nrow(filter(temp, !is.na(text))) > 0){
    temp <- filter(temp, !is.na(text))
    df2[i, ] <- temp[sample(nrow(temp), size = 1), ]
  }else if(nrow(filter(temp, check)) > 0){
    temp <- filter(temp, check)
    df2[i, ] <- temp[sample(nrow(temp), size = 1), ]
  }else{
    temp <- filter(temp, !(grepl("None",temp$newtext)))
    df2[i, ] <- temp[sample(nrow(temp), size = 1), ]
  }
}
```

Output example:

```
> df2
  id text check newtext othervars
2  1  asd  TRUE      as         1
1  2 <NA>  TRUE     das        45
3  3 <NA> FALSE     qwe         6
```

Greetings.

Edit: Ignore the row numbers on the left, they are residuals from the different subsets within the loop.

Comment: thanks for this code. it works quite fast for my dataset although i have about 400k observations.

Comment: I don't know why, but I also failed with simple indexing like df[!is.na(df[2:3],]. It resulted in a lot all-NA rows...
filter(df, !is.na(df[2:3]) did it for me. Thanks for reminding.